# Custom string case function in Lua 4

Tags: string, lua, lowercase

I am modding a video game that uses Lua 4.

The function `strlower` is unavailable to me due to the game designer's choices. The following functions are also unavailable to me.

```
strbyte
strchar
strfind
strlen
strrep
strsub
strupper
```

How would I write a custom function that does the same thing as `strlower` given the above limitations?

Do I only need to worry about ASCII characters? Or does Lua 4 do Unicode as well?

Comment: Do you have `gsub`?  `strlower` does not work with Unicode strings.

Comment: No luck with `gsub` either.

Comment: Hello - Does this ```getmetatable(_VERSION).__index.upper('make me great again')``` working for you? - Then try ```getmetatable(_VERSION).__index.lower('I AM THE GREATEST')```

Comment: Post a full list of functions available to you.

Comment: My example is from Lua5.3 so it cant work in Lua4.0. Sorry for that. I compiled Lua4.0 just to see how it differ from Lua5.3. The short  way to reach the same function is in Lua5.3 ```_VERSION.lower('I AM GOING TO BE SMALL')``` But this isnt possible too in Lua4.0.

Comment: I think `print` is the only one, besides the functions the developers themselves created.